# unable to reproduce disparity map and point cloud

Tags: matlab, computer-vision, point-clouds, stereoscopy, disparity-mapping

The point cloud output of my stereo image pair seems to be very inaccurate and strange. I believe this may be caused by an incorrect disparity map since nothing in the disparity map looks discernible compared to the stereo images. What methods do I need to use to obtain a correct disparity map and ultimately a correct point cloud?

I can provide the camera parameters if requested.

```
% load stereo images and camera parameters
load('stereoFrames.mat')
load('stereoParameters.mat')

% read stereo images
frameLeft = stereoFrames{1};
frameRite = stereoFrames{2};

% undistort and rectify stereo images
frameLeftRect = undistortImage(frameLeft, stereoParameters.CameraParameters1);
frameRiteRect = undistortImage(frameRite, stereoParameters.CameraParameters2);
[frameLeftRect, frameRiteRect] = rectifyStereoImages(frameLeftRect, frameRiteRect, stereoParameters, 'OutputView', 'valid');
frameLeftGray = rgb2gray(frameLeftRect);
frameRiteGray = rgb2gray(frameRiteRect);

% obtain disparity map and point cloud
frameDisparity = disparity(frameLeftGray, frameRiteGray);
framePoints = reconstructScene(frameDisparity, stereoParameters);
pointCloud = pointCloud(framePoints);
```

**Left Stereo Image**

[image: Left Frame]

**Right Stereo Image**

[image: Right Frame]

**Disparity Map**

[image: Disparity Map]

**Point Cloud**

[image: Point Cloud]

Comment: Did you rectify your images? If not, it is obvious that the disparity map will be inaccurate.

https://de.mathworks.com/help/vision/ref/disparity.html
Input image referenced as I1 corresponding to camera 1, specified in 2-D grayscale. The stereo images, I1 and I2, must be rectified such that the corresponding points are located on the same rows. You can perform this rectification with the rectifyStereoImages function.

Comment: @John as you can see in the code, the images were undistorted and also rectified before producing the disparity map.

Comment: @John could it be that the result of the rectification was incorrect due to wrong camera parameters?

Comment: I see that you are rectifying frameLeftRect & frameRiteRect, and you apply the disparity function on frameLeftGray & frameRiteGray.

The wrong alignement in the disparity map indicates (in my opinion) that there is a problem of rectification. Otherwise, the baseline is relatively high compared to the distance of your objects.

Comment: @John i realized that I forgot to include the `frameLeftGray` and `frameRiteGray` variables and I've updated the code. What do you mean by the baseline?

Comment: I do not know whether you are using your own dataset or a public one. Basically, the baseline is the distance between the principale points of the left and the right cameras. In case it is high and the distance to the objects is small, there is a significant differeance between the projections on both images. Thus, many points might be lost. 

See page 14: http://soe.rutgers.edu/~meer/TEACHTOO/STEREO-13.pdf

Comment: @John i am using my own dataset produced by using a 3d fujifilm stereo camera. I also noticed that the baseline was very high compared to that of sample images I've seen elsewhere. I'm not sure but I think I am able to change the setting of the baseline of the camera but I didn't since I used the default recommended setting.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/148410/discussion-between-john-and-senyokbalgul).